# Cordova Phonegap( iOS ) - How to download image file from URL into iOS image gallery

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I tried this, it works on android phone.  In iOS, I could show 'The image has been downloaded' alert, but I couldn't find the image in iPhone image gallery.

```
var path = 'http://example.com';

if( navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE ) {
  navigator.notification.alert('unable to download an image due to disconnect network.');
  return;
} else {
  var uri = encodeURI(path);
  var fileName = path.split('/').pop();
  var filePath = fileSystem.root.toURL() + fileName;
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

  fileTransfer.download(uri, filePath, function(entry){
    navigator.notification.alert( 'The Image has been downloaded.')
  });
}
```

Comment: Which Cordova Version ?

Comment: have you checked the native url from the downloaded entry?

Comment: Cordova Version is 4.0.0